# How to itrate the json list?

Tags: java, jquery, json

I have a list,that list i have put inside the json object that list I want to iterate using jquery and I need to append to the table.Could anyone please help me to solve this.

This is my action class.

```
    String startdate = request.getParameter("startdate");
    String endate = request.getParameter("endate");
    String leavepolicyid = request.getParameter("leavepolicyid");
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    LeavePolicyEntity lpe = (LeavePolicyEntity) session.get(LeavePolicyEntity.class, Integer.parseInt(leavepolicyid));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Calendar fromcal = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromcal.setTime(sdf.parse(startdate));
    Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCal.setTime(sdf.parse(endate));
    int actualDays = 0;
    boolean excludeWeekends = lpe.isExcludeweekends();
    int totalDays = 0;
    List daysList = new ArrayList();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    while (!fromcal.after(endCal)) {
        sb.setLength(0);
        System.out.println("fromcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)" + fromcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        if (excludeWeekends) {
            if ((7 != fromcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) && (1 != fromcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))) {
                actualDays++;
//                  String asWeek = dateFormat.format(fromcal.getTime());
                sb.append(dateFormat.format(fromcal.getTime()) + "-" + sdf1.format(fromcal.getTime()) + ",true");
            } else {
                sb.append(dateFormat.format(fromcal.getTime()) + "-" + sdf1.format(fromcal.getTime()) + ",false");
            }
        } else {
            sb.append(dateFormat.format(fromcal.getTime()) + "-" + sdf1.format(fromcal.getTime()) + ",true");
            actualDays++;
        }
        daysList.add(sb.toString());
        fromcal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        totalDays++;
    }
//        System.out.println("daysListdaysListdaysList" + daysList);
//        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
//        json.accumulate("weekdays", daysList);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String json = new Gson().toJson(daysList);
    System.out.println("Json" + json);
    response.getWriter().print(json);
```

**Jquery ajax**

```
 $("[id^='leavetype']").change(function() {
        var startdate = $('#leavetypefromdate').val();
        var enddate = $('#leavetypetodate').val();
//        alert(startdate)
//        alert(enddate)
        if (startdate != "" && enddate != "") {
            if (new Date(startdate) <= new Date(enddate)) {
                $.get("leaverequestvalidation.do?method=validateleavetype", {startdate: startdate, endate: enddate, leavepolicyid: $('#leaveTypeid').val()}, function(responce) {
                    alert(responce);
                    $.each(JSON.parse(responce), function(idx, obj) {
                        alert(1);
                    });

                });
            } else {

                alert("FromDate Cannot Be Greater Than ToDate")
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It would help if you just post your JSON Object here

Comment: Wht you are asking? I had post my all code without ajax call.

Comment: SO that the answer could start on the ajax call from jquery and easier to read.